# KSP parachutes not deploying

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have several parachutes to slow my craft on Duna. I set their altitude at 1500m and their atmosphere setting to 0.5, yet they do not deploy. They turn blue when I activate them with space bar but they do not deploy. The persistence file says they are STOWED. I did use quick load but only while out of the atmosphere and the parachute were not deployed. I also tried putting them as the last stage as there was an old bug about that. When I right click them before pressing space bar, there is the button to deploy them. When I stage, the button disappears. Going in EVA doesn't allow me to repack them as they have never been used.

Is there anything else I didn't think about checking?

Comment: Is this on Kerbin, or another planet/moon?

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/184260/7969

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you set the chute to deploy at a pressure of 0.5 atm. The maximum (sea level) pressure on Duna is 0.2 atm, so your chutes will never reach the 0.5 needed to deploy.